# On parsing a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, import-from-csv

I have this project for the university where they're asking me to create a simple bank system in Java. So far I've been able to do well except when it comes to store data for using it next time..

Lately I've found the storing code where all of my data are stored on a text file as :

```
int  str     str    int
5487,Samer,Lebanon,1000000
8792,Ahmad,Lebanon,2500000
```

and so on using the io libraries such as :

```
public static void saveToFile(int[] accounts,String[] names,String[] addresses,int[] balances,int maxTmp) {
    bubbleSorting(accounts,names,addresses,balances,maxTmp);
    try {
    //What ever the file path is.
        File statText = new File("C:/Users/Wicked Angel/Desktop/customers.txt");
        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        for(int i=0;i<maxTmp;i++)
            w.write(accounts[i] + "," + names[i] + "," + addresses[i] + "," + balances[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        w.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem writing to the file customers.txt");
    }
}
```

The difficulty is when I'm trying to import that text file and set each value to its specific array..

Any help ?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for sharing with us the hard parts of your project, but what is the problem?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410480/csv-reading-in-java

Comment: http://goo.gl/pzE4QL this is the full project 
on the bottom of the file there's the part that i can't figure it out!

Comment: Have you had a look at OpenCSV or SuperCSV? What you're after is parsing a CSV file which you can do in a few lines to process your example but keep in mind that there's a generally accepted specification of the CSV format (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) and that you will probably want your code to be robust. Hence, take note of the specs, write a little toy code to show your understanding and use a library for this purpose in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to read the text file line by line

```
// your file
File statText = new File("C:/Users/Wicked Angel/Desktop/customers.txt");
// read file using FileReader class
FileReader fr = new FileReader(statText);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
// the first line is the header line and might be ignored
String line = br.readLine();
// loop through each line by reading it from the buffer
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // process each line
}
br.close();
```

This will loop through each lines in your file. The `line` will be a string. Here below is an example of the first string in the while loop.

```
line: "5487,Samer,Lebanon,1000000"
```

What you have to do is to separate each parts and bring it to an array. This can be done with the [`Split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method from `String`-object. (click on the method name to read the documentation).

```
String[] myParts = line.Split(",");
```

The result will be then

```
myParts: ["5487"] ["Samer"] ["Lebanon"] ["1000000"]
```

That's an array. Just go through the above array and store each variable in the appropriate array. The first element in `ArrayList<int> accounts`, the second element in `ArrayList<String> names` ... Here below is an example for the first element

```
// outside loop 
ArrayList<int> accounts = new ArrayList<int>();

// inside loop 
accounts.Add(Integer.parseInt(myParts(0))); 
// since it should be an integer, I parse it to int before adding it
```

The reason behind the use of `ArrayList` is because you don't know how many lines you have in your text. Ofc you can check it, but performance wise, it's advisable to use a dynamic array, which is `ArrayList`. (Or other list objects if you want). If you want to read more about `ArrayList`, please refer to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to create, add element, get element, ...

Oh, also don't forget to cast the first and third element to int, or you will get errors when trying to add these info in an `int` ArrayList. If you want, you can also validate each element to ensure that you don't have faulty data (like the result of splitting a line is an array of three elements, which is incorrect).

This should help you to solve your import problems. Good luck

Comment: I tried the code u gave me and after br.close i tried to split the text but it's giving me an error which is 'no suitable method found for split(char)'
what's wrong !:\

Comment: you should use the double quote `"`, not the single quote `'`. The parameter of the method is a `String`-type, not `char` !

Comment: while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // process each line
}

what is the process ?

Comment: well, i meant handle the line (from the text file); split the string first, using the Split() method. Then add the elements to the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

use your ',' as the delimiter. read each line and seperate them using delimiter like, say if i wanted to extract String text="holy,molly" i would do

String holy=text.substring(0,text.indexOf(','));

and

String molly=text.substring(text.indexOf(','))

Comment: i have about 1000 person you're saying that i have to type a code for each

Comment: put them within a loop !

Comment: @user2707760 You should use the `split` method of a `String` instance instead. Also, your example does not address the case of two or more separators `,`. Work it out if you care but you'll end up rewriting `split`.

Comment: @okiharaherbst yes indeed ! split is a more feasible and complete solution to the problem. Thanks indeed !